# I am getting a No such table error in Django

Tags: django, database, migrate

I have read lot's of questions/answers trying to solve this. I am currently working on a website. The problem I am getting is the following:

1. All my website was working
2. Then I added two new models and changed 2 models name's
3. After that I did 'python manage.py makemigrations'
4. And 'python manage.py migrate'
5. Everything seemed okay, but when I went to admin page (after adding the models to admin) the two new models and the models that I have changed names are not working. When I click on them in the admin page I get 'No such table: <table_name>'.

I am going to show you...

models.py

```
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.theme}'


class Question(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Title")
    theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    content = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


class UpVote(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Answer(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


# ARTICLES___________________________________________________________________________________________


class ArticleTheme(models.Model):
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.theme}'


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    theme = models.ForeignKey(ArticleTheme, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf', null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_altered = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)


# Posts______________________________________________________________________________________________


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


# Subjects___________________________________________________________________________________________


class Subjects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    teachers = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

So now, I can't do anything with those tables, not even open the webpages in witch they were used.
I know this is not a lot of information, but the problem must be from the database. I started using django 2 months ago and I always used without getting an error like this.

Thank you for reading :) Hope you can help me!

Comment: did you override anything from django admin page?

Comment: try to do makemigrations and migrate once more, also check if u have changed the database name in the settings file